# Where can I find a C#/.NET NFS implementation?

Tags: c#, networking, nfs

Is there any implementation of the [NFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System_(protocol)) protocol written in C# or a good documentation thats easy to read so I can implement my own..

Both server and Client are needed but the client doesn't have to be C#, there must be some thing out there?

Comment: Just looking for some background information.  Why are you wanting to implement NFS yourself?

Comment: I have a Tvix if you know what that is a MediaPlayer for my tv and it uses NFS to stream from the computer, i want to be able to extend the content it can deliver and add some functions that i could add if i had my own NFS implementation.

Comment: Just to clarify i ended up writing my own implementation from ground up including the XDR Serialization.. it was a lot of fun doing and i must say the guys at sun where smart when they designed the protocol and i learned a alot in the process!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you weren't looking at this as a learning experience I would have suggested taking a C++/C implementation and wrapping it via C++/CLI.

However the only mention of an open source windows client for NFS 4 is [this project](http://www.citi.umich.edu/projects/nfsv4/windows/) with the financial support of MS and the university who wrote the reference implementation for many other OS's

That that this is their [statement of intent](http://www.citi.umich.edu/projects/nfsv4/windows/CITI-MS-SoW.pdf) and suggests a two year project sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can check at my open source project http://code.google.com/p/nekodrive
You can use directly NekoDrive.NFS c# library that wraps my implementation
of V2 e V3 NFS Protocol (V4.1 is coming).. It doesn't support the full protocol yet but It works for basic browsing/download/upload functions..

hope this helps

Comment: i implemented my own nfs engine by now :P

Comment: hehe.. I'm a bit in late :D Anyway I had a similar problem than yours (in my case speaking with nfs server on vxworks from windows) and I implemented my own solution. I released the code to open source hoping this helps avoiding to somebody the RPC protocol :D

Answer (score 1):

You could try porting Alfresco JLAN Server to C#.  It's written in Java but the two languages are very similar.

> Alfresco JLAN uses a virtual file
>   system interface that allows you to
>   plug in your own file system
>   implementation with the core server
>   handling all of the network protocol
>   exchange between the client and
>   server. JLAN is also the only Java
>   implementation of Window’s CIFS
>   (Common Internet File System), in
>   addition to supporting NFS and FTP.

http://www.alfresco.com/products/aifs/

Comment: A couple more java NFS implementations: http://galaxy.sourceforge.net/ includes a client as an example, http://void.org/~steven/jnfs/ is a server and http://yanfs.dev.java.net/ is a client...

Answer (score 1):

Given that [NFS](http://www.isi.edu/in-notes/rfc1813.txt) is based on [ONC RPC](http://www.isi.edu/in-notes/rfc1831.txt) and [XDR](http://www.isi.edu/in-notes/rfc1832.txt), I recommend using an XDR implementation for C#, such as [RPC.NET](http://www.onc-rpc-xdr.com/products/rpc/rpc-dot-net.asp).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend starting with the latest stable source code of NFS, and then run it from Cygwin (see below).  You would then start with a fully-functional well-tested NFS client and server, which you could then tweak as you desire.

Try this site: [Cygwin NFS Server HOWTO](http://www.csparks.com/CygwinNFS/index.xhtml)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a remotetea port that seems to work http://sourceforge.net/projects/remoteteanet/

Answer (score 0):

These links may help:

The first is a Code Project article describing an implementation of a C# NFS Server

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/NFSServer.aspx

The second is the public github repo. that contains the source

https://github.com/petebarber/NFS

Comment: wouldn't recommend this one. the source is a mess and the app doesn't work as outlined in the documentation provided. also using out of date methods.

Answer (score 0):

I've started an NFS v2 server based on jnfs (a java implementation of an NFS server) in C#.

The project is hosted on github here https://github.com/shellscape/Snarf

Comment: Well i have implemented my own by now, one question why did you pick version 2? it does not support files larger than 2gb...

Comment: I have a note in the readme that development for v3 of the protocol is next. v2 is the simplest implementation and provided a good way to get familiar with the communication, to learn how things worked. I felt a functional v2 implementation was a good launching point for a solid v3 implementation.

Great to hear you have your own going. I'd encourage you to post it on github or other open source website!