# Accessing linux file system in a C# program

Tags: c#, linux, filesystems, interop

I am programming a C# application that checks the last time a file was modified on 3 different servers, one of these being linux. Being a different file system what are the possible ways to check when said file was last modified on the system.

I have full access to modifying the server to an extent but I am looking for a number of creative solutions to get round this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you accessing the linux filesystem at the moment from your code?

Comment: I have not started to code it up yet I am looking for ways to do this first as I have never had to do it in the past

Comment: OK. How is the linux filesystem exposed? SMB? Something else?

Comment: At the moment its not exposed at all, I am asking for suggestions on how to expose and access it to use in my c# application

Comment: I've updated my answer and suggested another solution instaed of exposing it via samba.

Comment: How is your application run? Is it running on servers, or from another machine? If the latter, how does it access non-Linux servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing, if your application is going to run on a windows box is to run and configure [SAMBA](http://www.samba.org/) on the linux box and use it to expose the linux folders a network shares using [SMB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block).

This will allow you to access the linux folder the same way you would access any other windows network share.

Other options are to use NFS on the linux box and use an NFS client (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234720/where-can-i-find-a-c-net-nfs-implementation) SO question), or try mono directly on the linux box.

Comment: I ended up creating a c++ agent to sit on the box and ftping across from the windows program thanks for your help, and support :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`System.IO.File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file_members.aspx) classes static methods to get information you need:

```
    DateTime written = File.GetLastWriteTime(fileName);
    DateTime accessed = File.GetLastAccessTime(fileName);
    DateTime created = File.GetCreationTime(fileName);
```

This should work for files shared by your linux server via samba too. Also you can run this .Net code with mono on the linux machine - but it seems that not all linux filesystems [support all of the above methods properly](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=425751).

**Update:**

You could use a ftp and poll that instead of a network share. To access the date time filed you can [send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequestmethods.ftp.getdatetimestamp.aspx) a ftp-webrequest with [`WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetDateTimestamp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229711.aspx) to the server.

But maybe I've got your requirements wrong: do you need to check files from one machine on 3 machines? Or should those 3 machines check their files independently from each other? Are the results meant to be gathered by one "service"? Or are the results only relevant to the one machine the file belongs to?

Comment: Is there any way to get round this not using samba as the version of linux installed on the box is stripped down for its application

Comment: It seems that only `GetCreationTime` method might not be supported (as underlying file systems just don't store file creation time - see `man 2 stat`). Question is about modification time, which should work.

Comment: You could remotely access Linux file systems using (amongst others) SMB, NFS and SSH. Only SMB is supported by Windows though, so to use NFS or SSH you'll have to hack with your Windows box, or support those protocols in your application.

Comment: My c# application simply needs to go over to the linux file system get the file see when it was last accessed and return this back to the application where further processing takes place

Answer (score 0):

For linux the most obvious solution is SFTP. Most linux distributions have SSH/SFTP server built-in and running by default. Now, SFTP protocol provides a standard listing format for directories so that you can get the listing and read file times there.