# .NET NFS server implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, nfs

I maintain the management UI for an embedded device running a proprietary RTOS, which communicates with the manager over a simple socket. We have recently added a NFS client to said device, which runs NFS v2 or v3, so that it can access files over the network. I'm looking for a way to dynamically serve up a folder on the machine running the management app, to the device, from our management application, which is written in C# .NET 3.5.

So what I'm faced with is needing NFS server objects of some kind that I can instantiate, configure, and launch in code, then pass the info for the NFS share over to my device, which will then mount the share. Once the device is done, it will disconnect and tell me it's done, at which point I can shut down and dispose of the server object.

I've dug around a bit and found a few Java NFS servers, but nothing for C#. I found an excellent NFS client here (http://code.google.com/p/nekodrive/), but it seems to offer no serving functionality. Is there anything out there that does what I'm looking for, or am I going to have to write my own server from scratch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234720/where-can-i-find-a-c-net-nfs-implementation/13442223#13442223 None the less, for future visitors, I've started an NFS server implementation in C# here - https://github.com/shellscape/Snarf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Services for Unix ([SFU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Services_for_UNIX), see external links for download detail), ensure you install the NFS server, and configure away.  Then, in your .net app, use regular IO.

Comment: This is a package we sell to customers, and I can't ask them to install SFU on every computer they want to run this on. OS is Integrity, I wish it was vxworks...

Answer (score 2):

In the Windows world, best practice is to install this kind of optional resource for the customer as part of installation.  You'll need to check to see if SFU is redistributable by reading the license agreement supplied with the SFU download.  If so, write logic in the install routine to determine which SFU applies to the operating system the customer is using - there's different packages for 2003 and 2008 server.